# GCC Bitwise Attribute

Tags: c, gcc, attributes

What does GCC's `__attribute__(bitwise)` mean? The attribute isn't mentioned in the info pages of GCC-4.6. I stumbled upon it in the file `open-iscsi-2.0.871/include/iscsi_proto.h` in source the project **Open-ISCSI** where it is used as

```
...
/*
 * If running svn modules we may need to define these.
 * This should not go upstream since this is already properly defined there
 */
#ifdef __CHECKER__
#define __bitwise__ __attribute__((bitwise))
#else
#define __bitwise__
#endif
#ifdef __CHECK_ENDIAN__
#define __bitwise __bitwise__
#else
#define __bitwise
#endif

/*! initiator tags; opaque for target */
typedef uint32_t __bitwise__ itt_t;
/*! below makes sense only for initiator that created this tag */
#define build_itt(itt, age) ((__force itt_t)\
    ((itt) | ((age) << ISCSI_AGE_SHIFT)))
#define get_itt(itt) ((__force uint32_t)(itt_t)(itt) & ISCSI_ITT_MASK)
#define RESERVED_ITT ((__force itt_t)0xffffffff)
...
```

I'm suspecting something involving *byte-order* but I can't make any sense of the snippet given above.

Answer (score 18):

This is apparently not used by GCC but by [Sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse), a semantic parser for C used by the Linux kernel. It is documented in [Documentation/dev-tools/sparse.txt](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/dev-tools/sparse.rst).

Answer (score 1):

Google says [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-03/msg00265.html) that bitwise don't mean much anymore.

Comment: It sure does mean something! If you're writing a Linux device driver and running on a big endian device but the controller is sending you messages in little endian, you better make sure you use the proper __le_to_cpu( ) macros in the appropriate places.

Answer (score 1):

https://lwn.net/Articles/689907/:

> `bitwise`, which creates a "new" type ([in the Ada sense](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/%7Edale/ada/aln/4_basic_types.html#RTFToC12)) that is identical to some other integer type except that it is incompatible with it [...] `bitwise` [can be used](https://lwn.net/Articles/689907/) to avoid confusing big-endian and little-endian values, or to avoid accidentally using bitmasks on the wrong variable