# typedef __u32 __bitwise __be32 means in linux

Tags: c, linux

I extract from file (http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/HAWK/IPTables-libiptc-0.52/include/linux/types.h ) these defines :

```
#ifdef __CHECKER__
#define __bitwise__ __attribute__((bitwise))
#else
#define __bitwise__
#endif
#ifdef __CHECK_ENDIAN__
#define __bitwise __bitwise__
#else
#define __bitwise
#endif

typedef __u16 __bitwise __le16;
typedef __u16 __bitwise __be16;
typedef __u32 __bitwise __le32;
typedef __u32 __bitwise __be32;
#if defined(__GNUC__)
typedef __u64 __bitwise __le64;
typedef __u64 __bitwise __be64;
#endif
typedef __u16 __bitwise __sum16;
typedef __u32 __bitwise __wsum;
```

what does   #define **bitwise** _*attribute*_((bitwise)) mean?

and what does typedef __u32 __bitwise __be32; mean?

Comment: `__attribute__((bitwise))` is used by a checker (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931063/gcc-bitwise-attribute). As for the other typedef, it depends what `__u32` is in that case. Typically, it will be an unsigned 32 bit number.

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand those macros, I recommend you to read this article: [Sparse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse). Anyway, this question seems to be a duplicate from this: [GCC Bitwise Attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931063/gcc-bitwise-attribute)